Flood: Layer error: Image.lt: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands. Got 0 and 1
I'm trying to copy the code of the video below but for my area Greece. It's about the Daniel flood.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIoVwsAb_Pk&ab_channel=GeomaticsEngineering
I write the code as below:
var aoi = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq("Dist_Name","Daniel"));
Map.addLayer(aoi,{},'aoi')

//import the satellite image collevtion

var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
.filterBounds(aoi)
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains("transmitterReceiverPolarisation","VV"))
.select('VV')

//filter the before and after flood imagery

var before = collection.filterDate("2023-09-01","2023-09-02").mosaic()
var after = collection.filterDate("2023-09-13","2023-09-14").mosaic()

var before_clip = before.clip(aoi)
var after_clip = after.clip(aoi)

//apply smoothening filter

var before_s = before_clip.focal_median(30, "circle", "meters")
var after_s = after_clip.focal_median(30, "circle", "meters")

//difference

var difference = after_s.subtract(before_s)

var flood_extent = difference.lt(-3)
var flood = flood_extent.updateMask(flood_extent)

//display maps
Map.addLayer(before_clip,{min:-30, max:0},"Before_flood")
Map.addLayer(after_clip,{min:-30, max:0},"After_flood")
Map.addLayer(difference,{},"difference")
Map.addLayer(flood,{},"Flood")

The error is:

Flood: Layer error: Image.lt: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands. Got 0 and 1.

Has anyone any idea? I think I tried everything.

The issue you're encountering is that your date filters are returning empty images due to no matches found. The datasets you are querying may not be updated frequently, and since you are searching for images from a specific day, it's possible there were no images captured on that date. I recommend using a broader temporal range to increase your chances of finding images. If you want to quickly check the available image dates in your collection, you can print the collection and review the image IDs. For instance, in the example you provided, there are no images for 2023-09-01. The nearest available dates are 2023-08-30 and 2023-09-06.

